# Windows.Form Pixel Scaling

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

We are using .NET/Mono/Xamarin to write a cross-platform application.  We essentially render everything a single full-form picture box, so that the code is 98% the same for all 4 platforms we support (Android, iOS, WinCE, and now Windows).

For iOS and Android, we can auto-scale the final rendered result.  Essentially, we render our application to small resolutions, and then have the final blit to screen upscale everything to a higher resolution screen, making it fill the screen.   Yes, it can look pixelated, but that is fine with us.  For example, we're rendering to 768x1024 size now, but this is showing fullscreen on iOS on a retina display with resolution of 1500x2000.  The rest of our application still thinks we're rendering to the small form size (768x1024).

I'm looking for a similar facility for Windows.Forms.  Essentially, I'd like to simply set the form resolution to something like 768x1024, but have it scale it up to 1536x2048 automatically.

Why?  Because of the Surface Pro, which sports resolutions of 3000x2000, etc.  We'd like to continue writing our pixel-based application to render to lower resolutions, and have it automatically blitted to a higher resolution form.

I tried Windows.Forms.Scale() property but this seems to have no effect.  This appeared to be what we're looking for.

Essentially what we'd like to do is:
 1. Set base Form Size to 1024x768 (landscape)
 2. Set Form.Scale to 2.0f.
 3. Poof... the form magically appears on the screen as 2048x1536 pixels (so it fills most of the Surface Pro screen, BUT, the rest of the entire application still sees the base form size as being 1024x768.

In short, we want a Form to *appear* on the screen as bigger than it's true resolution, scaling up each of the raw pixels into something bigger, to make it more visible on super-high-rez screens (like the Surface Pro).

I hope I'm making sense here.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't using the DPI-aware auto-scaling? That should make your form "readable" on Surface just fine.

Comment: Also, how exactly are you "rendering everything in a picture box"? `CreateGraphics`? `Image`?